# How to use for and while loops to find unique multiples of a list of factors

Tags: python

Given a list of factors and a limit, add up all the unique multiples of the factors that are less than the limit. All inputs will be greater than or equal to zero.

Example
Suppose the limit is 20 and the list of factors is [3, 5]. We need to find the sum of all unique multiples of 3 and 5 that are less than 20.

Multiples of 3 less than 20: 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18
Multiples of 5 less than 20: 5, 10, 15

The unique multiples are: 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 15, 18

The sum of the unique multiples is: 3 + 5 + 6 + 9 + 10 + 12 + 15 + 18 = 78

So, the answer is 78.

```
def sum_of_multiples(limit, multiples):

    n = 1
    sum_m = []

    for i in multiples:
        while i*n < limit: 
            sum_m.append(i*n)
            n+=1
            if i*n > limit:
                break
                
    return sum(sum_m)
```

The test results came back as "your tests timed out" suggesting the code is running slowly or there is an infinite loop or something similar so I am not able to see the error made.

Thinking it was an infinite loop issue, I modified the code to cater for break

```
def sum_of_multiples(limit, multiples):

    n = 1
    sum_m = []

    for i in multiples:
        while i*n < limit: 
            sum_m.append(i*n)
            n+=1
        else:
            break
                
    return sum(sum_m)
```

and tried another if statement

```
def sum_of_multiples(limit, multiples):

    n = 1
    sum_m = []

    for i in multiples:
        if i*n < limit: 
            sum_m.append(i*n)
            n+=1
                
    return sum(sum_m)
```

The if method was wrong as the answer was incorrect, but the else method that I used above gave me the same time out error. Wasnt sure what else to do.

Comment: Infinite loop? No, you quickly return `63`. Why aren't you asking about *that*?

Comment: Title says *"How to use for and while loops to find unique multiples of a list of factors"*. So is it a requirement to use for and while loops?

Comment: No, am experimenting on for and while loops in this question.

Comment: I wasn't able to get 63 in the editor, the error message I got was a timeout due to infinite loop, so I didn't ask about that

Comment: What "editor"? And how do you know it's infinite instead of just too slow?

Comment: Am using Exercism to practice python, the error message "your tests timed out" came back suggesting the code is running slowly or something similar to an infinite loop

Comment: I don't know Exercism, but there are plenty of ways to test this however you want. Do they tell you how large the limit can be? (Although I suspect at least as likely the problem is indeed an infinite loop, from an input number you already explicitly  mentioned but didn't test).

Comment: No, they didn't mention the limit (I didn't manage to find anything), but they did mention it could be their infrastructure issue.

Comment: Omg is that site annoying. How much do I need to solve to "unlock" that problem? Sigh...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```py
def sum_of_multiples(limit, factors):
    multiples = set()

    for factor in factors:
        multiple = factor
        while multiple < limit:
            multiples.add(multiple)
            multiple += factor

    return sum(multiples)
```

(I renamed `sum_m` to `multiples`, `i` to `factor` and `multiples` to `factors` to make it a bit more readable, but they are still the same)
So:

```py
print(sum_of_multiples(20, [3, 5]))
```

prints `78`.

There are two problems with your program:

1. `n = 1` needs to be called in the for loop.
2. Duplicates are counted separately.

To fix the second problem, I used a set (which can't have duplicates, and therefore disregards them) instead of an array.

Comment: Yes, now it's what I meant. I just realized that they (and you) indeed have an infinite loop, though, so you'll have to cover that to earn the upvote back :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy, as far as I can see, it doesn't. If I am overlooking something, please could you let me know (or edit yourself).

Comment: Read the question's first paragraph carefully.

Answer (score 0):

```py
  def sum_of_numbers(limit,multiples):
      list_of_numbers=[]
      for i in multiples :
          for n in range(1,limit):
              if n*i>=limit:
                  break
              list_of_numbers.append(n*i)
       return sum(set(list_of_numbers))
```

I think You can use this code its much `easier` and It's `simpler`.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that this solution will cover all your conditions:

```py
def sum_of_multiples(limit, multiples):
  l1 = []
  for i in multiples:
    mul=1
    while i*mul<=limit:
      l1.append(i*mul)
      mul+=1
  sum_of_multiples = sum(list(set(l1)))
  return sum_of_multiples
```

Comment: Thank you - I am new to python but I think the list in the second last sentence may not be needed? Since it is already defined as a list at the top?